# HTML Emails appear blank in Yahoo

Tags: email

Im trying to install a good newsletter script for some basic email marketing. The thing is that my yahoo just dont want to display HTML emails. I sent some html test emails to myself through several scripts and from my yahoo account aswell,but all appear blank.

It's quite odd because my magento's html emails are being received correctly,but others [ and even YAHOO emails! ] arent.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: curious, but are you checking your spam dir?  Also, are you properly setting the MIME type of the email?  Also, have you tried sending html emails to other email recipients?  Google?  Live? ...etc

Comment: Well,in headers mime-version appear to have the value "1.0" and the emails are getting in inbox aswell as in spam folder. The same thing with gmails also. Can you recommend a good and free newsletter that is able to send HTML emails?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of a good recommendation.  Though if they are getting junked/spammed it tells me something looks suspicious about the mail being received, either the content or the sender.  Try adding the sender to the safe senders list.  If gmail/yahoo perceive an email as a threat they will mitigate the risk by now loading the threatening content.  This prevents bots or fishers from getting valid hits off of peoples emails.

Comment: Eh,sounds complicated. I managed to use magento's newsletter system and the emails sent through it are matching my demands.Many thanks for your time and intentions. Goodbye.

Comment: awesome, glad you were able to get it to work.  Sorry I couldn't be of much help! :)

Answer (score 1):

- Changed the content type and encoding in the settings for each of the velocity templates to HTML / UTF-8
- Added a  to each of the emails with the standard charset="UTF-8" declaration. Maybe Yahoo doesn't strip out the head like most other email clients.
- Added the HTML 4.01 strict declaration to the top of the email:

> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem myself.
Here is what I found:
Older [article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3317/correct-doctype-to-use-in-html-email/), but still useful: 
they recommend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
```

Which seems to work for everyone except Yahoo.
Instead, use the following for Yahoo:

```
<!doctype html>
```